# Creating a new folder each time Selenium takes a screenshot

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework, screenshot

I'm using Python + Robot framework + Selenium to take screenshots of a few urls. This is the code:

```
output = self.builtin.get_variable_value("${OUTPUT DIR}")
time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S")
folder = "New_folder" + time
path = os.path.join(output, folder)
for url in url_list:
    driver.get(url)
    driver.save_screenshot(path + "/" + url + '.png')
```

The idea is to create a new, unique folder each time the code runs, and saves the screenshots inside it. But it doesn't work and the folder is not created. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are mixing variables names here.
Instead of

```py
time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S")
folder = "New_folder" + now
```

It should be

```py
time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S")
folder = "New_folder" + time
```

While `time` is not a good name for a variable.
I'd advice to use something like:

```py
current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S")
folder = "New_folder" + current_time
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I updated my code to show that in fact it was like "folder = "New_folder" + time". Still doesn't work. I think the problem is somewhere with "driver.save_screenshot(path + "/" + url + '.png')". But I don't see it.

Comment: can you debug and see what is the actual value of the following variable: `path`.

Comment: This:
C:\[...]\robottests\output\New_folder2022-02-15 15.37.22

Comment: So it appears to be a correct string for creating the folder. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: maybe you should not allow dots `.` in that string? Try changing the `%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S` format

Comment: I appreciate the time you are spending on this. I changed the format to "%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S". Still nothing. The problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: It's OK. I'm just trying to debug the issue with your help :) I will try to find the problem and it's solution

Comment: I see that ` driver.save_screenshot` method should accept a `'/path/to/file'` while you are also passing `url` there while url will normally be not a valid string to be a part of file path. Also it may be too long..

Comment: In case that is the issue I will update the answer accordingly

Comment: I answered my own question!

Comment: OK, I see. Interesting

Answer (score 1):

OK I found the problem. I had to generate the whole path before `save_screenshot, and create the folder. Something like this:

```
path = os.path.join(output, folder)
os.makedirs(path)
for url in url_list:
    driver.get(url)
    file_address = path + "/" + url + '.png'
    driver.save_screenshot(file_address)
```